# Efficient Method To Display Group Title Once — PHP/MySQL/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

There are three tables in MySQL: Employees, Branches, Departments. I need information to appear in the following way:

> **ATLANTA Branch**
>  *Delivery Department*
>  Phillip J. Fry
>  Phone: 123456
>
> *Engineering Department*
>  Turanga Leela
>  Phone: 123457
>   
>  Bender Rodriguez
>  Phone: 123458

The simple PHP code currently:
1) Takes rows from three tables (simple SELECT query with JOIN)
2) Puts them in row (mysql_fetch_assoc)
3) Displays using the PHP While loop

The result is then like this:

> **ATLANTA Branch**
>  *Delivery Department*
>  Phillip J. Fry
>  Phone: 123456
>
> **ATLANTA Branch**
>  *Engineering Department*
>  Turanga Leela
>  Phone: 123457
>  
>   **ATLANTA Branch**
>  *Engineering Department*
>  Bender Rodriguez
>  Phone: 123458

What technique (JS, jQuery, Ajax) or method can you recommend so I can pull row information using only one query and not duplicate the Branch name and Department name?


**UPDATE:** If I put the branch name outside the loop (using While loop), there would be multiple loops: 1) To get a branch, 2) To get a department, 3) To get all employees in that department. Loop.


**UPDATE:** Sharing the code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die('Connection error.');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);
mysql_select_db("eReference");

// Check Employees
$query = "SELECT Employees.fName, Employees.lName, Department.deptName, Branch.branchName, ".
"FROM Employees ".
"LEFT JOIN Department ".
"ON Employees.department = Department.id ".
"LEFT JOIN Branch ".
"ON Employees.branch = Branch.id ;";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>

<h2><?php echo $row['branchName']; ?></h2>
<?php if ($row['deptName']) echo "<h3>" . $row['deptName'] . "</h3>"; ?>
<h4><?php echo $row['fName'] . " " . $row['lName']; ?></h4></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You should not echo atlanta beach in your loop. place it out

Comment: Put Atlanta Branch outside the while loop...may be it will work..

Comment: Yeah, but then I would have multiple queries: 1) To get all branches, 2) to get all employees.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I will happily do so. Give me several minutes.

Comment: So, I have put the code. Guys, thank you for considering my problem and your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

Create a multi-dimensional array with the data, and iterate through the array to render the output.

This will not be the most efficient in terms of memory usage, but unless you have thousands of rows of data, it probably won't be an issue.

The benefit of this, is that the html rendering code is much simpler and easier to understand, plus sql and html are not intermingled. (which is good for code maintenance)

```
<?php
// Create connection
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die('Connection error.');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);
mysql_select_db("eReference");

// Check Employees
$query = "SELECT Employees.fName, Employees.lName, Department.deptName, Branch.branchName, ".
    "FROM Employees ".
    "LEFT JOIN Department ".
    "ON Employees.department = Department.id ".
    "LEFT JOIN Branch ".
    "ON Employees.branch = Branch.id ;";
// note you probably want to add an order by statement here too, to ensure consistent sorting

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();

// build a multi-dimensional array from the result set
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $data[($row['branchName'])][($row['deptName'])][] = array(
        'name' => "{$row['fName']} {$row['lName']}",
        'phone' => $row['phone'] // add phone, doesn't exist in original query, but just to illustrate how it would work
    );
}

// sql finishes here

?>

<?php
    // html rendering 
    // use htmlentities to escape any html chars, such as < > etc

    foreach ($data as $branchName => $departments) {

        echo '<h2>',htmlentities($branchName),'</h2>';

        foreach ($departments as $deptName => $employees) {

            foreach ($employees as $employee) {
                echo '<h3>',htmlentities($deptName),'</h3>';
                echo '<h4>',htmlentities($employee['name']),'</h4>';
                echo '<h4>',htmlentities($employee['phone']),'</h4>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: So, I follow your method, and logically it works better than the one I  originally had in my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

   $i = 1; // to be incremented after printing branchName once

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

     if($i == 1) { ?>

        <h2><?php echo $row['branchName']; $i ++;  ?></h2>

     <?php } ?>

     <?php if ($row['deptName']) echo "<h3>" . $row['deptName'] . "</h3>"; ?>

     <h4><?php echo $row['fName'] . " " . $row['lName']; ?></h4></p>

   <?php } ?>
```

Just add a variable `$i = 1` and check before printing if it is equal to 1. After printing it for first time, increment it. 
It is just addition of an **if** statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This one is also what I thought about. I will try this one also. Looking for the most efficient method :-)

Comment: Sandesh, thank you for the tip. I used the iteration and with some minor change in the SQL query everything worked fine. I will post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The result gotten from your sql should be an array so use a while loop to iterate throw the array while echo the result of the current index

Answer (score 0):

```
   $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
  $newarray = array();
  $i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $newarray[$i]['deptName'] = $row['deptName'];
 $newarray[$i]['fName'] = $row['fName'];
$newarray[$i]['lName'] = $row['lName'];
$i++; 
}
<h2><?php echo $newarray[0]['branchName']; ?></h2>
while($newarray){
?>
<?php if ($newarray['deptName']) echo "<h3>" . $newarray['deptName'] . "</h3>"; ?>
<h4><?php echo $newarray['fName'] . " " . $newarray['lName']; ?></h4></p>
}
```

?>

Comment: I will try this solution, but is it a good idea to duplicate the already existing array in $row?

Comment: Thank you, Sanj, for your time and response, I truly appreciate it. I tried the code, however, it (visually) took more time than the method with If-clause. I will post how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work..

```
<?php
$deptName;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ($row['deptName'])
    {
        if ($deptName != $row['deptName'])
        {
            echo "<h3>" . $row['deptName'] . "</h3>";
                        $deptName = $row['deptName'];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Prodeep, I get your logic. It's brilliant, in fact, but in order to make the solution dynamic, using variables as Sandesh suggested and making some minor change to the SQL query are the best. I will post the answer after five hours (not enough of reputation).

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what it did:

```
$query = "SELECT Employees.lName, Employees.fName, Employees.mName, Position.position, ".
                    "department.deptName, department.deptId, ".
                    "Branch.branchName, Branch.branchId, ContactInformation.* ".
                    "FROM Employees ".
                    "LEFT JOIN Position ".
                    "ON Employees.position = Position.id ".
                    "LEFT JOIN Department ".
                    "ON Employees.department = Department.deptId ".
                    "LEFT JOIN Branch ".
                    "ON Employees.branch = Branch.branchId ".
                    "LEFT JOIN ContactInformation ".
                    "ON Employees.contactInformation = ContactInformation.id ".
                    "ORDER BY Employees.branch, Employees.department ASC;";

            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

            $arrayOfEmployees = array();

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $arrayOfEmployees[($row['branchName'])][($row['deptName'])][] = array(
                    'lName' => $row['lName'],
                    'fName' => $row['fName'],
                    'mName' => $row['mName'],
                    'position' => $row['position'],
                    'lPhone1' => $row['lPhone1'],
                    'lPhone2' => $row['lPhone2'],
                    'mPhone' => $row['mPhone'],
                    'fax' => $row['fax'],
                    'office' => $row['office'],
                    'email' => $row['email']
                );
            }

            foreach($arrayOfEmployees as $branchName => $arrayOfDepartments) {
                echo "<h2>".$branchName."</h2>";
                foreach($arrayOfDepartments as $deptName => $arrayOfEmployeeContacts) {
                    echo '<h3>',htmlentities($deptName),'</h3>';
                    foreach($arrayOfEmployeeContacts as $employeeContacts) {
                        echo "<h4>".$employeeContacts["lName"]." ".$employeeContacts["fName"]." ".$employeeContacts["mName"]."</h4>";
                        echo "<p>";
                        if($employeeContacts["position"]) echo $employeeContacts["position"]."<br>";
                        $num = $employeeContacts["lPhone1"];
                        if($employeeContacts["lPhone1"]) echo "+".substr($num,0,1)." (".substr($num,1,4).") "." ".substr($num,5,2)."-".substr($num,7,2)."-".substr($num,9,2)."<br>";
                        $num = $employeeContacts["lPhone2"];
                        if($employeeContacts["lPhone2"]) echo "+".substr($num,0,1)." (".substr($num,1,4).") "." ".substr($num,5,2)."-".substr($num,7,2)."-".substr($num,9,2)."<br>";
                        $num = $employeeContacts["mPhone"];
                        if($employeeContacts["mPhone"]) echo "+".substr($num,0,1)." (".substr($num,1,3).") "." ".substr($num,4,3)."-".substr($num,7,2)."-".substr($num,9,2)."<br>";
                        $num = $employeeContacts["fax"];
                        if($employeeContacts["fax"]) echo "+".substr($num,0,1)." (".substr($num,1,4).") "." ".substr($num,5,2)."-".substr($num,7,2)."-".substr($num,9,2)."<br>";
                        if($employeeContacts["email"]) echo "<a href=\"mailto:".$employeeContacts["email"]."\">".$employeeContacts["email"]."</a><br>";
                        if($employeeContacts["office"]) echo "Кабинет — ".$employeeContacts["office"];
                        echo "</p>";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Tested. The solution works well dynamically — just add more branches and departments into the database. Here is the efficiency check against the method I originally used (in microseconds):

```
        Array-based Original
1       1.015       1.012
2       1.016       1.02
3       1.026       1.013
4       1.015       1.002
5       1.026       1.02
6       1.014       1.02
7       1.013       1.019
8       1.005       1.014
9       1.013       1.006
10      1.021       1.015
Average 1.0164      1.0141
```

Comment: Have you tested to see what happens if you delete a branch and your branch id's are no longer sequential? I think @Prodeep's concept is a better generic solution.